# Xcode merge conflict plist.info not correct and storyboard of unknown type

Tags: xcode, git

I recently had a bug in a released app and branched off master.

I fixed the bug, changed the version number, and attempted to merge into master - at which point, I was shown my changes and noticed a red C next to info.plist and main.storyboard.

I canceled the merge and investigated.

Clicking info.plist presents me with an error:

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

I ran plutil and there's an error at line 22 which is between `<key>` and `<string>` for the build number. `>>>>>>head` was on that line, so I deleted the line and saved info.plist. I ran plutil again and there are no errors.

Clicking main.storyboard shows several changes, though I didn't make any.

I attempted to merge again after correcting Info.plist, and got an error that I was in the middle of an operation. I discarded the changes at the command line and tried to merge again. Both files still show the red C with Info.plist still indicating that there's an error with it.

Comment: Classic example of why I doesn't use StoryBoards.. Million conflicts with obfuscated XML and all sorts of crap.. one developer using a different version of Xcode, etc.. In any case, search for <<<< and >>>> in both files and see.

Comment: ^Exactly welcome to storyboard life! You need to go over changes one by one storyboard xml and choose which one to use.

Comment: Thanks guys, I just ended up making the changes in master instead. The .plist issue was never sorted out even though I corrected the error

Comment: Same problem here. After the merge I was left with a dangling commit, and Xcode kept refusing to open the info.plist and refusing further commits with 'in the middle of an operation". I was able to overcome this by making a commit from terminal. Didn't feel good so I restored from a pre-merge backup. An interesting exchange with @matt left me with the impression that the merge failure had caused git to leave merge failure text in the info.plist, and that is what makes the plist unreadable to Xcode. I will avoid plist and storyboard merges like the plage now, shame. Didn't know plutil, thx.